# Reflection type to string differs in IDE and in code

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a logger that abstract calls to NLog. I want each logrow to have its caller origin. Some code with generics, result in strange caller names:

**ProxyService`1[MyNameSpace.IController]**

In the IDE, when I hover over the variable caller, it popups op the right name:

{**MyNameSpace.ProxyService**}

How can I get same value as the one the IDE pops up with ?

Codesample:

```
private void SetLogEventInfo(object caller, ILogger logger)
        {
            string callerOrigin = null;

            if (caller != null)
            {
                callerOrigin = caller.ToString();
            }

            <code removed>
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get result similar to IDE's by concatenating:

```
Type type = value.GetType();
return type.Namespace + "." + type.Name;
```

You'll get `` MyNameSpace.ProxyService`1 `` this way. `` `1 `` bit refers to the number of type arguments in the generic type. Without it, the name is ambigous. If you insist on removing it, you can use usual string operations (`IndexOf`, `Remove`).

Comment: @PatrickPeters This cannot be. Concatenation of three strings one of which is "." can't produce a string without ".". :)

Comment: @PatrickPeters As Athari said you'll still get `1. which you can strip off as well using string operations.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, our IDE shows you your class name in the C# notation, `System.Reflection` is language-agnostic, hence the difference.

Second of all - don't rely on `ToString()`. It will show the type name only if it wasn't overridden (hence the default `Object` implementation is used). There are multiple valid scenarios where you want to override `ToString()`, which would break your code.

Mimicking C# code formatting is AFAIK not available out of the box, but there are some tricks to do this, e.g.:

```
var cSharpProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
var variableDecl = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(caller.GetType(), "_");
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
{
   cSharpProvider.GenerateCodeFromStatement(variableDecl,
                                            sw,
                                            new CodeGeneratorOptions());
}
sb.Replace("_;", String.Empty);
var callerOrigin = sb.ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach, but I doubt it's reliable enough. There's no guarantee that the code generator will produce `" _;\n"` in the end and no other "noise".

Comment: Athari, C# declaration of a variable called `_` must end with " _;". I'm also 99% positive that C# CodeDomProvider generates a new line by default when using `GenerateCodeFromStatement`. Care to provide an example where this would differ?

In other words - I'm generating a very specific C# statement, so it must contain " _;". Do you believe that the provider would in some circumstances ignore the rules of the language and just introduce some 'noise"?

Comment: Ok, changed the way the variable name declaration was removed - hope we can agree there's no ambiguity there now.

Comment: My point is, it's an implementation detail. It can fail in the next version of .NET. I'd rather see the code check that the string actually ends with the characters you expect and only then modify the string.

Comment: a. if you honestly believe that variable declaration might change in .NET 6.0, I'm afraid I don't have a reply to that, other than I personally find it unlikely. b. as mentioned above, I've implemented your suggestion before you actually wrote it ;) `StringBuilder.Replace` is functionally equivalent to checking and only then modifying in this case.

Comment: `"TypeName _ ;"` is perfectly valid output from the code generator and your code fails in this case (produces garbage).

Comment: Fair point - you can fix that by doing a simple regex replace instead, but hopefully this exercise can be left to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

The object's `ToString` method is being called, which, if not overridden, will simply return the type name, equivalent to:

```
public string ToString() {
    return this.GetType().ToString();
}
```

You can override ToString if you like, but that obviously won't work for types you have no control over. For example, if an instance of `List<string>` was passed into that method, you'd end up with:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

And that's probably no good to you. So, the best bet would be to modify the above code to format the type:

```
callerOrigin = FormatObjectForLog(caller);
```

Where the method may do something like (you can fill in the blanks, since I don't know enough about your requirements to decide what to do with cases other than *ProxyService`1*):

```
string FormatObjectForLog(object obj) {
    if (obj is IFormattable)
        return obj.ToString();

    if (obj.GetType().IsGenericType) {
        // Get rid of `1 and other crud...
    }

    ...
}
```

One version of a sanitised type formatter that gets rid of backticks is the following:

```
public string FormatType(Type t) {
    if (t.IsGenericType) {
        return string.Format(
            "{0}.{1}<{2}>",
            t.Namespace,
            t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.IndexOf('`')),
            string.Join(", ", t.GetGenericArguments().Select(FormatType))
        );
    }

    return t.ToString();
}
```